# Adding a click event to a dynamic button rendered through a literal

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, htmlwriter

I have a dynamic button which is being rendered through an ASP:Literal

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

Button btnOpenFile = new Button();
btnOpenFile.ID = "BtnOpenFile-" + additionalReadingFileID;
btnOpenFile.Text = "Open";
btnOpenFile.CssClass = "SettingsChangeButton";
btnOpenFile.Click += new EventHandler(OpenFileInLocation);
btnOpenFile.RenderControl(writer);

writer.Close();
sw.Close();
this.LitAdditionalReadingContent.Text = sb.ToString();
```

The methods being added to the click event is

```
protected void OpenFileInLocation(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  Change Selected ID to this one
    Button clickedLink = (Button)sender;
    int fileID = Convert.ToInt32(clickedLink.ID.Replace("BtnOpenFile", ""));

    IRPBestPracticeTopicAdditionalReadingFile myOpenFile = new IRPBestPracticeTopicAdditionalReadingFile(fileID);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@myOpenFile.FilePath);
 }
```

This works when i add a button on the ASP page and assign the click event to the button on the page load method, but doesnt seem to register when i am assigning it to a dynamically created button being rendered via a literal.

**Does anyone know why? And is there a simple solution to this problem?**
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render a control as a literal. However, no event will be attached to those control. In other words, the click event will not be fired when the button posts back to server.

You want to add a control as a control using **PlaceHolder** or **Panel**.

**The trick is you need to reload those dynamic control back in Page_Init with same ID.** Otherwise, they'll become null, and event will not be fired.

Here is an example -

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btnOpenFile = new Button
    {
        ID = "BtnOpenFile-" + 1, 
        Text = "Open", 
        CssClass = "SettingsChangeButton"
    };
    btnOpenFile.Click += OpenFileInLocation;
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btnOpenFile);
}
```

### ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ... %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're not *rebuilding* the control on `Load` for the event to get bound. You need to cache enough information to *rebuild* the control on load and add it to the control hierarchy where it belongs so that the event can be bound and fired.